# Bootstrap 4 remember tab

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the browser to remember which tab the user was viewing when the page is refreshed or revisited ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
```

Profile
      
      
         Messages
      
      
        Settings

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at local storage.

Comment: Or cookies. This isn't really specific to Bootstrap.

Comment: Cool. Does anyone have code snippets on how to do that ?

Answer (score 12):

This did the trick for me..

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var hash = $(e.target).attr('href');
  if (history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, hash);
  } else {
    location.hash = hash;
  }
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
  $('.nav-link[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Creates sharable links using the URL hash.

Comment: This works for going forward, do you know how to listen to back changes?

Answer (score 5):

This is the multiple tabs example :

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {

    var theTabId = $(this).attr('href');
    var activeTabs = (window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab') ? window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab').split(',') : []);

    var $sameLevelTabs = $(e.target).parents('.nav-tabs').find('[data-toggle="tab"]');

    $.each($sameLevelTabs, function (index, element) {
        var tabId = $(element).attr('href');
        if(theTabId != tabId && activeTabs.indexOf(tabId) !== -1){
            activeTabs.splice(activeTabs.indexOf(tabId), 1);
        }
    });

    //unique tabs
    if (activeTabs.indexOf($(e.target).attr('href')) === -1) {
        activeTabs.push($(e.target).attr('href'));
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab', activeTabs.join(','));

});

var activeTabs = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if (activeTabs) {
    var activeTabs = (window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab') ? window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab').split(',') : []);
    $.each(activeTabs, function (index, element) {
        $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + element + '"]').tab('show');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do it. Obviously, this won't quite work since the snippet is on stackoverflow.com and the hash won't be appended to the url. I tested this locally though and it works.

**Note:** *This will only work if you refresh the page or otherwise use the specific URL that refers to the tab to be opened. If you want it to "remember" the tab after you close the browser/tab or whatever, you would probably be best off using cookies or perhaps storing it in a database if you are dealing with client sessions.*

```js
//When the page loads, get the current # value and mark the li as "active" if the href attribute matches.
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = "#" + window.location.hash.substr(1);
  $("#myTab li").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).children().first().attr("href");
    if (href == v) $(this).addClass("active");
    else $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
});

//Whenever we click on a li, remove all "active" classes and finally add "active" to the one we clicked.
$("#myTab li").on("click", function() {
  $("#myTab li").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save a value for after refresh, You can use `cookie` or `sessionStorage` (as said in comments). The easier is sessionStorage i think.

```
$('.tab-pane').click(function(){
   sessionStorage.setItem("clicked", $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And after page refresh, you can retrieve the saved value:

```
 if(sessionStorage.getItem("clicked") != null)
     var clickeId = sessionStorage.getItem("clicked")
```

Comment: With this solution though you cannot have a shareable link.

Comment: Great thanks loads. So if I have the id, How do I set it as active on page load ?

Comment: You can do any thing with an element that you have it's id: `$('#id').addClass('active')` or `$('#id').css('background-color', 'red')` or .....

Answer (score 1):

I used local storage to store the active-tab-id and it works for me.

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("click", function(e) { 
   localStorage.setItem("active-tab-id", $(e.target).attr("href"));
 });

var activeTabId = localStorage.getItem("active-tab-id");
var activeTab = $(`a[href="${activeTabId}"]`);

if(activeTab.length == 1)
  activeTab.tab("show");
else
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]')[0].click();
```

if your tab is not activated, by default it's clicked on the first tab.